# Copying to Pendrive freezes at 100%

Tags: filesystems, usb-flash-drive, file-transfer

I have a Sandisk Cruzer Blade 16 GB pendrive with me. Previously I had 4 GB Transcend. I had copied number of file >700MB into Trancend without any problem. But Now, when I try to copy a 700Mb media file, it is fast at begining upto 30%, and when it reach to 100% it takes some seconds (>20 seconds) to finish copying. How can I remove this last freezing process? Do I need to change file system in pendrive?

Comment: Have you tried copying the files to your hdd first, then copying them to your new flash drive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably related to the disk cache. To speed things up many OSes don't do the copy or write operations in real-time. Instead, they build up a queue of write operations, and then work through the queue in the background so that the actual copy / cut / delete operation can "complete" much faster from the user's perspective of allowing them to continue working with the computer. However, the data still has to actually be written to the flash drive, and that's probably what is going on while it waits at 100%. Usually this doesn't become too apparent when the read speed is close to the write speed (i.e., copying files from one location on a drive to another location on the same drive), but becomes more noticeable when there's the destination drive is considerably slower at writing than the source is at reading.

To answer your question, changing the filesystem probably won't help much (what's the current filesystem? What's your current OS?), and the easiest way to fix it if this is the issue is to get a faster flash drive.

Looking at the [feedback](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820171505) on the drive, many users are complaining that the drive is simply very, very slow.

Comment: This answer would be better without the generic claim about speed of pendrives (speed is very model specific, and in the age of USB 3.0, many pendrives are faster than rotating SATA disks).  Write cache is used on hard disks also.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks for the pointers :) I haven't had the luxury of a USB3 flash drive yet, so my mental image of them still lags back to the early USB2 and the USB1.1 era of flash drives.